# Prevent code editing for certain projects in VS solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently working on splitting a large C# solution into several smaller solutions grouped by function.

Currently, there is a server component and a client tool set, all dependent on a core library.
The server projects have been moved into their own solution, and I am using a reference to the compiled output of the solution containing the library.

Preferably, I would like the core library to be available in the server solution so that I can refer back to the code.

Is there a way that an existing project can be added to a solution such that it can be compiled against, but prevent and code in this newly added project from being edited?

Comment: Do you use TFS? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397448/reference-project-readonly-in-visual-studio

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thank you, I had searched but my wording wasn't precise. And no, I don't use TFS.

Comment: Another option is to use nuget and copy the packages to a shared drive (ie host them internally), rather than publishing to the nuget gallery.

Comment: @DavidArno Thanks, I didn't realise you could use NuGet locally! I have used it in the past with an Artifactory repo, but if they can be run from a location on the disk, I can simply have the core library build script copy the compiled libraries to there.

Comment: @Alex, check out https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds for detailed info on locally hosting nuget packages

Comment: @DavidArno That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Dave, I was very close to using Maven for this!

Comment: @Alex, I can go to sleep tonight knowing I've increased the net happiness of the world by enabling someone to avoid using Maven :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @DavidArno solves this -

> By @DavidArno check out docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds for detailed info on locally hosting nuget packages

Answer (score -1):

You can refer back to the code during debugging without including the original project in your solution.

You just need to configure Microsoft's [Source Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641(v=vs.85).aspx) tool.